# Simple 2D matrix rotation in OpenGL with GLSL produces no output

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glsl, glut

I'm starting to learn about OpenGL and doing some early examples to understand the API how to use it. The I'm currently stuck on, is with a rotation example. The code, (provided bellow) is supposed to create a 2D square from 4 vertices and apply a rotation of 30º around the Z axis. Apparently, the code seems fine and I've seen it running in my professor's machine and it works. If I draw the square without applying the rotation inside the shader, the program draws the square, but with no rotation, of course.

Could this be caused by some bad configuration? All the other examples seems to work fine.

Here is the code:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include "Angel.h"

glm::vec2 vertices[4] = {
    glm::vec2( -0.5, -0.5 ),
    glm::vec2(  0.5, -0.5 ),
    glm::vec2(  0.5,  0.5 ),
    glm::vec2( -0.5,  0.5 ),
};

const int NumPoints = 6;
glm::vec2 points[NumPoints];

void square( ){
    points[0] = vertices[0];
    points[1] = vertices[1];
    points[2] = vertices[2];
    points[3] = vertices[0];
    points[4] = vertices[2];
    points[5] = vertices[3];
}

GLuint matRot;
void init( void ){
    square();
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    GLuint program = InitShader( "vshader1.glsl", "fshader1.glsl" );
    glUseProgram( program );

    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                           BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

    matRot = glGetUniformLocation( program, "rot" );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); 
}

void display( void ){
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );    

    glm::mat4 rotZ; 
    rotZ = glm::rotate(rotZ, glm::radians(30.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matRot,1,GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(rotZ)); 

    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumPoints );  
    glFlush();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA );
    glutInitWindowSize( 512, 512 );
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutCreateWindow( "square rotation" );

    glewInit(); 

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

The `Angel.h` is an additional resource that helps with some management of all those libraries. It can be found [here](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/include/Angel.h) and the `InitShader` implementation is [here](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/CODE/Common/InitShader.cpp)

The vertex shader:

```
#version 130

in vec4 vPosition;
uniform mat4 rot;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = rot * vPosition;
}
```

If I don't multiply `rot * vPosition`, the "un-rotated" square is drawn

And the fragments shadder:

```
#version 130

out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
```

Comment: How does this matter ? It may rotate by wrong angle and not by 30 degrees. But OP is saying he doesnt see any rotation.

Comment: The static method is `glm::degress(30.0f)` rigth? I tried this way, but still a blank window

Comment: You will need to upgrade the graphics card drivers for this. New graphics card drivers will come with new version of OpenGL and GLSL.

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni I have version 0.9.9-a1 and tried both way (with `glm::degress(30.0f)` and with `30.0f` and didn't work as well

Comment: I think just update the driver also change to double buffering replace
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA ); to 
glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA );

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni yhea, I try upgrade them. Using ` glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB )` showed a weird transparent window.

Comment: Have you tries driver upgrade?

Comment: Not yet, I'm searching how to do this right now

Comment: @LucasHenrique: Don't forget to change your `glFlush()` to `glutSwapBuffers()` if you switch to `GLUT_DOUBLE`.

Comment: Changed to glutSwapBuffers() and the transparent window is the white back ground window I had before

Answer (score 2):

Workin' fine on my machine with FreeGLUT, `GLUT_DOUBLE`, & GLM 0.9.8.4:

[image: screenshot of rotated square]

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

glm::vec2 vertices[4] =
{
    glm::vec2( -0.5, -0.5 ),
    glm::vec2(  0.5, -0.5 ),
    glm::vec2(  0.5,  0.5 ),
    glm::vec2( -0.5,  0.5 ),
};

const int NumPoints = 6;
glm::vec2 points[NumPoints];

void square( )
{
    points[0] = vertices[0];
    points[1] = vertices[1];
    points[2] = vertices[2];
    points[3] = vertices[0];
    points[4] = vertices[2];
    points[5] = vertices[3];
}

GLuint matRot;
void init( void )
{
    square();
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    const char* vert = GLSL
    (
        130,
        in vec4 vPosition;
        uniform mat4 rot;

        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = rot * vPosition;
        }
    );

    const char* frag = GLSL
    (
        130,
        out vec4 fColor;

        void main()
        {
            fColor = vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
        }
    );
    GLuint program = Program::Load( vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL );
    glUseProgram( program );

    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

    matRot = glGetUniformLocation( program, "rot" );

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ); 
}


void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );    

    glm::mat4 rotZ; 
    rotZ = glm::rotate(rotZ, glm::radians(30.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matRot,1,GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(rotZ)); 

    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumPoints );  

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even your code didn't work, my graphics driver must be outdated. I try upgrade them

Comment: @LucasHenrique: Are you getting the white background color and no square?  Or some other failure mode?

Comment: Only a white BG

Comment: @LucasHenrique: In your debugger (or via `printf()`/`cout`) check the value of `loc` and `matRot`, they should be non-negative.

Comment: @LucasHenrique: You might also try commenting out the VAO creation/bind.

Comment: With or without the VAO binding, `loc` and `matRot` are 0 at the end of the `init` function